# How to retrieve a content from FreeBase.com in Italian language?

Tags: freebase

How to retrieve a content from FreeBase.com in Italian language?
Now, I can only see content from [eng.wikipedia.org](http://eng.wikipedia.org).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the information in Freebase is language independent, but if you want Italian language strings, you can get them by specify that it your queries (the default is English if no language is specified).  There's an example app [here](http://translate.freebaseapps.com/?word=%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A1%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B3)

For things which are sourced from Wikipedia, the English language Wikipedia forms the basis, so if something only exists in the Italian Wikipedia, it won't be included.  For things which are in both, you can get links to both the English article and the Italian article (and you can't get the Italian name directly from Wikipedia or look things up by it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are making the call, but add this parameter to it:

```
lang=/lang/it
```